# Проблема с supervisor на Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, supervisord

Пытаюсь перезагрузить супервизор командой `sudo supervisorctl reload`. Получаю вот такую ошибку

> error: , [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   file: /usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py line: 228

Для команды `sudo service supervisorctl status`:

> supervisorctl.service
>
> Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
>
> Active: inactive (dead)

Comment: Ну видимо потому что нет `/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py`. Кстати. А почему не `systemd`?

Comment: Не знаю почему не systemd, так повелось, так работают на этом сервере все  проекты. Изначально в каком-то видеоуроке подсмотрел или типа того. Сокет на месте, просто он почему-то не хочет его признавать. В итоге решил проблему через явное указание файла конфигурации через флаг `-c`. Так работает.